# If some event is going to happen soon, what do you call it?

Tags: word-request

If some event approaches, what do you call it? I thought I could use 'close in', but it seems I can't. For example

> As the election day [approached], the candidates' confrontational rhetoric reached fever pitch.

It's not happened yet, but it's going to happen soon and it gets sooner and sooner, that's what I intend to convey. Please suggest something that works well in different contexts, for different types of events.

Comment: coming/upcoming/forthcoming/approaching/advancing/nearing (neutral) imminent/impending/looming (negative)

Comment: 'Drew near'. (@AndrewTobilko's suggestions are adjectives, but you seem to be asking for a verb.)

Comment: @KateBunting That's what I actually considered, but I didn't find it here (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/draw), so I thought it was a false recollection

Comment: Definition 2.4 is the most appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways of expressing that meaning. Your “approached” is one example.  But which of the many options to choose depends on several factors, including: whether you want a verb, noun, or adjective; whether the fact that the event is approaching is to be seen as a positive or negative thing; just how close to the event we are; how fast the event is approaching; and so on. Some examples:

> As election day **loomed**, the candidates’ rhetoric became increasingly depressing
>
> He knew that his **looming** election defeat would be followed immediately by ridicule and scorn.
>
> The **fast-approaching** exams had all the students on edge.
>
> As McEnroe served for the match, his heart beat loudly in his chest in expectation of his **imminent** victory.

Comment: I want a verb..

Comment: Can you suggest more verbs, other than 'loom'?

Comment: Another option is "drew near". But as I said, your own choice of "approached" is fine, and is probably one of the better options. It doesn't have the ominous overtones of "loomed", and is not as prosaic as "drew near".